# PHP PDO Calling public method in different class from other class

Tags: php

i'm trying to figure it out, how i can use public method in a class from another class. i'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
```

I have main class user which contains insert method, basically this method inserts values into database.

```
<?php
  class User{
    protected $pdo;
    public function __construct($pdo){
      $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields){
      //here we insert the values into database
    }
  }
?>
```

here is my config.php file to instantiate the classes so i can use them

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'database/connection.php';
    include 'classes/user.php';
    include 'classes/follow.php';
    include 'classes/message.php';
    global $pdo;

    $userObj     = new User($pdo);
    $followObj   = new Follow($pdo);
    $messageObj  = new Message($pdo);
?>
```

And i have other classes message, and follow. in follow class i can access all methods from user class, and in message class i'm trying to use insert method which in user class

```
<?php 
    class Message extends User{
        public function __construct($pdo){
            $this->pdo  = $pdo;
        }

        public static function sendNotification($user_id, $followerID, $type){
            //calling this method from user class 
            $this->insert('notifications', array('By' => $user_id, 'To' => $followerID, 'type' => $type));
        }
    }
?>
```

In follow class i'm trying to use sendNotification method, remember this method is in message class, and it use method from user class

```
 <?php 
    class Follow extends User{
        public function __construct($pdo){
            $this->pdo  = $pdo;
        }

        public function follow($user_id, $followerID){
            //here will be query to insert follow in database

            //now i need to sendNotification method from user
            Message::sendNotification($user_id, $followerID, 'follow'); 

        }
    }
?>
```

Getting Fatal error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
```

What should i do?

Comment: you cannot use `$this` in a static method

Comment: Since you are using oop principles, don't use global keyword. It's bad practice

Comment: Let's say i removed the static keyword, then how i can access the method in follow class?

Comment: Use static methods when the method doesn't depend on the class been instantiated. Hence the reason why $this can't be used

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't sendNotification be in the parent class(User)?

Comment: Did you require the user.php file in message.php? If not, required it before using.

Comment: @HujjatNazari no i didn't, and i don't want to. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Akintunde no user class gonna handle the user related methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `sendNotification` a non static function. Remove the `static` keyword

Use static methods when the method doesn't depend on the class been instantiated. Hence the reason why `$this` can't be used

In the follow function, do this instead

```
$message = new Message($this->pdo);//pass database connection 
$message->sendNotification();//pass the variables
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access $this from a static method in this method:

```
public static function sendNotification($user_id, $followerID, $type){
            //calling this method from user class 
            $this->insert('notifications', array('By' => $user_id, 'To' => $followerID, 'type' => $type));
```

You can make sendNotification non-static and create an instance of Message so you would be able to access public members of User

Comment: How?, i don't want to include file in a class.

Comment: $message = new Message();
$message->sendNotification(...);

If the class is already included it will work.
You can also have a look to psr-4 autoloading to make it easier

Comment: as you can see, in my config.php file i passed $pdo variable in classes. if i instance the class it'll will throw error.

Comment: Then pass it to the constructor

Comment: You can also create a `trait` with the PDO declaration inside and use it in classes, it will be carried, whether instance or not.